# List all methods of a given class, excluding parent class's methods in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

For some odd overriding checks, I am looking for a way to get a list of an object's methods which excludes the parent class's methods. So given this:

```
class Parent: 
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def papa(self): 
    pass
  def mama(self): 
    pass
class Son(Parent): 
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def papa(self): 
    pass
  def child(self):
    pass
```

I'd like a function `list_subclass_methods(cls,is_narrow)` that receives the class symbol, and returns: 
`['child']`
If the flag `is_narrow=True` is supplied, or
`['__init__','papa','child']`
If `is_narrow=False`

Multiple inheritance might be a problem - so in the case of multiple parents, we compare against the union of the parents' methods

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get List of all attributes which are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280605/get-list-of-all-attributes-which-are-not-inherited)

Comment: While the specified post is similar, this post is relevant for methods only. Thank you for the comment @Tomerikoo

Comment: @Mano the fact that you're only interested in methods doesn't make the post Tomerikoo linked too irrelevant - you just have to filter out non-method attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
import itertools
from types import FunctionType

def listMethods(cls):
    return set(x for x, y in cls.__dict__.items()
                 if isinstance(y, (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod)))

def listParentMethods(cls):
    return set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        listMethods(c).union(listParentMethods(c)) for c in cls.__bases__))

def list_subclass_methods(cls,is_narrow):
    methods = listMethods(cls)
    if  is_narrow:
        parentMethods = listParentMethods(cls)
        return set(cls for cls in methods if not (cls in parentMethods))
    else:
        return methods
```

**Explain:**

listParentMethods is a recursive function which get the union of the parents' methods.

Comment: The prefered way to test the type of an object is `isinstance(obj, cls)`. Also note that your code will fail on classmethods and staticmethods... And you may want to use sets to speed up the lookups.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers, are there any objects involved ? Mano talked about inheritance, so classmethods and staticmethods are not relevant. You've got a point on using sets.

Comment: @Philippe I'm afraid I don't get your point - in which way inheritance would classmethods and staticmethods "irrelevant" exactly ???  Those are herited just like any other class attributes.

Comment: `isinstance()` can take a sequence of classes as second argument, so you want `if isinstance(y, (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod))`